# How to copy a System.Drawing.Image value?

Tags: c#, .net, image, gdi+

I am trying to copy an Image value to draw on it and on second draw ignore the last one and start over on top of the preserved Image value. I.e.:

```
Image with 4 rectangle (ImageA)
-> draw a circle
return to ImageA
-> draw a rectangle
now there are 5 rectangles
```

I don't know if it's the optimal way to draw too?

Comment: Could you provide a little more info about your intent? Are you trying to create a simple undo/redo framework for image editing, or something more specific?

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to draw new shapes on an already drawn bitmap. So I don't wanna redraw my stuff. Just add on top, but only 1 new shape.

Answer (score 7):

I agree with Blindy. Create a new Image object and draw ontop of that while preserving your initial Image.

```
Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap("C:\\<path");
Image myImage = (Image)myBitmap.Clone();
```

This will create a new Image object for you to then do your drawing on whilst still preserving the original image that you've loaded.

Comment: Thanks but I only have an Image store, as in the System.Drawing.Image in memory. Can I just use that to pass to a new Image value?

Comment: Sorry i thought you we're loading an Image in as a Bitmap. 
Yes of course you can do what you're after. Say you're starting off with Image imageA and want to copy that image into a new object the code remains the same as above but without the casting.

Image myImage = imageA.Clone();

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Bitmap and put a Graphics object over it, then draw ImageA over the temporary bitmap and draw your circle on it, and when you're done dispose the temporary bitmap and keep drawing on ImageA.